# Recommendation for Emacs/Ruby setup

Tags: ruby, emacs

So far I'm very happy with my Clojure/Emacs setup but failed to come even close to this experience when using Ruby. I tried the enhanced ruby mode (no syntax highlighting) and robe (which fails with a syntax error as soon as the console is started). I would really appreciate any tips where to find some proper guidelines on how to configure Emacs for Ruby.

BTW: I do not need any Rails support. Just plain Ruby support.

Comment: Same here........... :(

Comment: > (which fails with a syntax error as soon as the console is started) < Why don't you try to file an issue?

Comment: Because I wasn't sure if this error was my fault. In the meantime I realized that the problem was an incorrect path definition in emacs that. Because of that Ruby 1.8 was used.

Comment: After a reinstall enhanced ruby mode is now working. After fixing a path problem robe is working to. Nevertheless I decided to deinstall robe since ctags navigation is a better fit for my style of working.

Answer (score 19):

I find the following setup quite good:

- ruby-mode from Emacs 24.4 or above - it's quite an improvement over the one in Emacs 24.3
- [inf-ruby](https://github.com/nonsequitur/inf-ruby) - a way to run irb/pry inside Emacs
- [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) - superb handling of delimiters like `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `do/end`, etc.
- [yari](https://github.com/hron/yari.el) - ri interface for Emacs
- [ruby-tools](https://github.com/rejeep/ruby-tools.el) - adds commands to turn a string to symbol, symbol to string, single to double quote string, double to single quote string, clear string, interpolate and more...
- [flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) + [RuboCop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) for on-the-fly linting and code style checking

AFAIK many rubyists are also using yasnippet. I've given up on trying to find a good "intelli-sense" alternative for Ruby in Emacs, but other than that I'd say the above setup is quite solid. It's pretty much what you'd get by using [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude)'s Ruby module.

Comment: yasnippet is nice. One problem I encountered is that I had to rename the ruby-mode snippets directory to enh-ruby-mode. Otherwise the snippets are not available in the enhanced ruby mode. RuboCop is really cool. But it seems that I have to set the LANG environment variable in .emacs. Otherwise I had problems with UTF8 sources. Instead of yari I decided to use dash-at-point.

Comment: Just a quick comment/question: do you think I should use Enhanced Ruby Mode? I'm using it now and I'm not 100% happy with it... And the repo seems a bit dead too.

Comment: No, don't use it. The idea was nice, but the implementation never got far. The built-in `ruby-mode` is pretty good these days.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a real answer since I'm not a Ruby user but I am tied into the Emacs community and these things have shown up on my radar before

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RubyLanguage (the wiki, although sometimes out of date, is a good place to start from for queries like this).
- http://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2013-09-26-setting-up-emacs-as-development-environment-on-osx/ was recently on HN and has a detailed setup.
- [Sacha Chua's chat with Avdi Grimm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l91IuT-VQ4I) mentions a few of the tools that Avdi uses for his Ruby work.